# JMeter - override jtl file in non GUI with dashboard

Tags: jmeter

When running [non GUI](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#batch) with dashboard several times and have irrelevant results , I want to override sometimes the jtl file created using `-l` command:

```
jmeter ... -l result.jtl -e -o ...
```

But I keep getting error for file not empty:

```
Error in NonGUIDriver java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Results result.jtl is not empty
```

How can I override in non GUI? I must delete manually the file before execution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per [user manual](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options), you can use:

> -f

or

> --forceDeleteResultFile

Which will force delete existing results files before start the test, which means only CSV is erased BUT not the report folder.

If you don't see this happening it's a bug which you seem to confirm:

- https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=61956

But if you see the result file deleted but not the report folder then it's a regular expected result. If you think it's not good, maybe report an enhancement request.

Answer (score 0):

As per [Full list of command-line options](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options) JMeter User Manual chapter:

> ```
> -f, --forceDeleteResultFile
>
>     force delete existing results files before start the test
> ```

So add `-f` argument to your command line and that would be it.

Also make sure you don't have any [Listeners](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/greedy-listeners-memory-leeches-performance-testing) configured to save results into `results.jtl` file, the good practice is to disable any listeners during load test execution.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
jmeter ... -f -l result.jtl -e -o ...
```

The `-f`, force delete existing results files before start the test. This also include the log files.

example:

```
sh /usr/local/Cellar/jmeter/5.5/bin/jmeter -n -t ../Load-Test.jmx **-f** -e -o ../report -l ../log/Pref
```