# Jmeter - Command Line Cannot write - folder is not empty

Tags: jmeter

I am executing the JMX file from non-GUI mode and the execution was successful, when i repeat the test again it shows me an error

> An error occurred: Cannot write to 'D:\Project\HRAPI_Test\Test\Results\Dashboard' as folder is not empty. errorlevel=1

How to resolve this? I want to overwrite the html reports on each execution and if possible to have different reports for each execution.

Comment: Similar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48057808/jmeter-override-jtl-file-in-non-gui-with-dashboard

Comment: Did the solution mentioned worked out for you ?

Comment: @Vittal need to open a bug

Comment: Any feedback on answer ? If ok it should be accepted and upvoted so that it's helpful to others

Answer (score 5):

Currently JMeter override only jtl file using `-f` [command line option](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options)

> force delete existing results files before start the test

There's a new [JMeter bug](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=62243): 62243 Dashboard - add option to override dashboard results

You can [vote](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/page.cgi?id=voting/user.html&bug_id=62243#vote_62243) on the bug. until it's fixed you need to delete dashboard folder manually before re execute command or change dashboard folder.

**EDIT**

Bug was fixed and resolved and available in JMeter's [nightly build](http://jmeter.apache.org/nightly.html)

Comment: When this fix will be available in a release version? for the time being,Is the nightly build safe to use in projects

Comment: @Vittal nightly is available if build tests are passing, but of course "Use at your own risk" and keep your previous JMeter version just in case

Comment: I have done a workaround to run a python script which deletes the folder , each time before the Jmeter test starts

Answer (score 0):

It's a protection from JMeter to avoid erasing critical data.

Create a shell file and call this:

> deltree <report folder>

Answer (score 0):

Its because the folder exists ... you can solver this create a parameter to concat with your path, like this:

```
$Date = Get-Date -Format ddMMyyyyhhmmss
jmeter -n -t 'jmetter\offer-dev.jmx' -l jmetter\TestResult-$Date.jtl -e -o jmetter\Results-$Date\ -X
```

// For all parameter, use this command

> JMeter --?